# how to extract/merge subtitle from/to mp4/mkv files?

Tags: mp4, video-processing, subtitle

A video file in mp4 is given. I need to extract a part of it into another video file without any change in format. I need just one subtitle get removed. What's the best method for this?

I tried avidemux, but it excluded all subtitles.

Comment: You probably did something wrong as avidemux should be able to do that. Apart from that, you can always use ffmpeg to do this (which code should be also the one in use within avidemux). Check out the docs. You need to selected the streams to keep and set everything which is remaining to copy-mode.

Comment: i tried ffmpeg (avconv), but it couldn't realize the source codec. it's x265 and i'm in ubuntu 12.04. i hope if i may use ffmpeg, i've not to use avidemux.

Comment: Then you used a totally outdated ffmpeg version. The general exaggerated rule is: if you got an decoder for format x, ffmpeg can decode format x too :-). (technically x265 is not a codec, but an encoder, h265 would probably the name of the standard)

Comment: i just installed ffmpeg. it should not be outdated. maybe h265 decode/encode is not enabled by default.

Comment: It was added in 2013 (decoder) :-). So without exact error-messages, there is no help.

Comment: http://paste.debian.net/971393/